# Why do dist-upgrade and upgrade give different held packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, held-packages

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libavcodec54 libavformat54
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
```

and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libavformat54
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

Why when I do a normal `upgrade` are both `libavcodec54` and `libavformat54` held back, but when I do a `dist-upgrade` only  `libavformat54` is held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are different goals in terms of APT, `apt dist-upgrade` upgrades system by upgrading, installing and removing; `apt-get upgrade` upgrades by only upgrading packages, `apt upgrade` upgrades system by upgrading and installing packages.